# (C#, Blazor) Reading Different JSON files with same data using File.ReadAllText gives differently encoded strings

Tags: c#, json, blazor

I have 2 Blazor Webserver projects where i read my data from a JSON file (Which contain `UTF16` characters).

In the first project, the data reader read the JSON file and stored a `UTF16` encoded string for the JSONSerializer to work with.
I started the 2nd project and since my needs for the file reading were same, i used the same code for data reading and made a new JSON file.

Here my problem occured, when i ran the code the `File.ReadAllText` returned a string with a different encoding. Since all the `UTF16` characters were replaced with "�".[image: Image of the data read]

I tried to solve this by forcing the `File.ReadAllText` function to use the `UNICODE` encoding, which just turned all the characters into unknown characters.

I even copied the data from project 1 to project 2, thinking maybe the data messed up somehow, but it did not work.

What worked was copying the JSON file from project 1 to project 2 and changing the data in there and it worked, the code (That was the same as in project 1) read the JSON file correctly. [image: Image of the working JSON file]

Then i tried to make a completely new JSON file and read it in both projects with the same data, but the result was `UTF8`
All the files had the exact same data in it, except for file 3 which had maybe indentation differences.

- Tooted is the original file in project 2
- Tooted2 is the copied file from project 1
- Tooted 3 is the new file in project 2

[image: Image of all 3 file data side by side]

[image: Image of all 3 file properties side by side]

What i want to know is why does the same code read different JSON files that have the same data differently and how can i work around this?

Edit:
After reading an article about encodings and "BOM"s i am still a little bit confused but the problem is a bit clearer.
I opened those files with hex byte view and even though the letters looked the same, the hex bytes were different.

Ill refer the working file as `file 1` and broken file as `file 2`

`File 1` hex code for word "Tööriist"
`54 C3 B6 C3 B6 72 69 69 73 74`

`File 2` hex code for word "Tööriist"`54 F6 F6 72 69 69 73 74`

There is nothing that i found that indicates a "BOM" or anything that identifies how characters are stored in them.
Ill leave the two file hex views here

[File 1 hexed.it link](https://hexed.it#base64+lzjb:Tooted.json;AHsNCiAgIlTDALbDtnJpaXN0AGFkZV90YXJ2AGlrdWQiOiBbKQQfICAIJiAAASJOCGltaQAYIktlZQhybWUAMGphIGsAb21wbGVrdCICLAwuICAiSGlugQQ/MTU2LjAwHBcQSW5mb1Q+LCAxEDUxdGsgRVBpbFRkaQhHLBhZUxQUWyIgJIQiLCAgxSIgKl0MMX0EB10IPiJBAGlhdGVobmlrBmEAglzYw7xsZ26AaWlkdWsgUwEJAGsgS0RMIDE2gDAgUHJvZmkgnuEQ4zQxNDBM5BxKIDY5dNROaQR7HMEIvCAgJ0GBHF8gqTIwYKk2MAH8qWRpZCI6IFsAICJOaWlkdWsAIiBdDQogICAAIH0NCiAgXQ0ACn0=)

[File 2 hexed.it link](https://hexed.it#base64+lzjb:Tooted3.json;AHsNCiAgIlT2APZyaWlzdGFkAGVfdGFydmlrQHVkIjogWwQdIAogCCQgAAEiTmltAmkAGCJLZWVybQJlADBqYSBrb22AcGxla3QiLAwuQCAgIkhpbgQ/MSA1Ni4wMBwXSW4EZm9UPiwgMTUxBHRrIEVQaWxkaZUIRywYWVMUFFsgJISIIiwgGMMiIF0MLwp9BAddCDwiQWlhgHRlaG5pa2EAgAFc1vxsZ25paWQQdWsgUwEGayBLAERMIDE2MCBQMHJvZmkgmxDgNDE8NDBM4RhJIDV00E5p5wR6HL8IuiAgQX0YXiCnJDIwYKc2MPynaWQAIjogWyAiTmkAaWR1ayIgXQ0ACiAgICB9DQoAICBdDQp9)

When i copied the hex data from file 1 to file 2, the code read the data correctly from the file 2 (only the copied part of it) So i see that the problem that those characters look the same while editing, but in reality they are different.

For now what the problem for me is when i tried writing "ö" to both files via notepad and checked the hex view again, the `file 1` got added the correct bytes and the `file 2` had once again the incorrect ones.

I do not understand what makes those files use different hex codes for the same letter.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: If I had to bet, my money would go on a Byte-Order-Mark ("BOM"). Find a Hex Editor or activate Hex editing and have a look. I am pretty sure you will find boms at the beginning of at least one of them if not all of them.

Comment: You may want to re-read *the* article by SO founder - https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/... This will either answer your question or at very least tell you what information you should [edit] into the question so others can debug your problem. As @Fildor commented we need HEX dump of sample files (try to limit it to 16 characters of text) and not images of some text.

Comment: "All the files had the exact same data in it" - if you've used different encodings, they *don't* have the exact same data. That's like saying a JPEG file and a PNG file are identical, just because they both represent an "all blue" image. You can tell they don't have "the exact same data" because they're different sizes...

Comment: "What i want to know is why does the same code read different JSON files that have the same data differently" - to go back to the image example, would you expect a PNG-viewer to accurately decode a JPEG? Because that's basically what you're doing when you call `File.ReadAllText(string)` for a file that isn't UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: I've added new information to the post via edit to the bottom. Thank you both for your help, it has helped me understand how things work, and for the article I read it today and sadly I did not find the information that i was looking for. I might've missed it but I did gain insight on other things. I am still quite new to posting on SO.

Comment: The files don't contain UTF16 and your own question proves that. In UTF16, all characters are saved as 2 (or more) bytes. The fact the US-ASCII characters weren't mangled but the non-US-ASCII were means that one of the files is UTF8 (file1) while the other was saved with a single-byte codepage.

Comment: How were those files created, especially `files2`? You can try guessing the actual codepage or you can fix whatever produced the file to actually use UTF8

Comment: I agree with Panagioits - it's better to require UTF-8 and keep the code simple than to try to work with multiple encodings.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i understand that, but how can i tell the difference what kind of encoding a json file uses? All of those files were created in Visual Studio, and to my knowledge you cant set anything like that when creating the file. What remains a mystery to me is WHY are they different if I created them the same way, and edited them the same way.

Comment: You can't, in general. (This isn't specific to JSON, it's for all text files. Although I'd normally *expect* JSON to be in UTF-8, given RFC 8259.) We can't really tell what you did in Visual Studio or what your settings are, unfortunately. But it does sound like this question isn't really about code any more, but about "How do I control which encoding Visual Studio uses for manually-created/edited files."

Comment: Because the developer saved them differently, or the developer's code used the system's ASCII codepage instead of UTF8. The solution is to always use UTF8. Your own question shows that file 1 is UTF8, because only `ö` was translated to two bytes. In the second file, it's `0xF6` which  *probably* is Latin 1/ISO-8859-1. . You can use a library like Python's `chardet` or .NET's `UTF.Unknown` to guess the encoding based on character frequencies but that can still fail if there isn't enough text

Comment: Okay i think i see now, i will try to use different methods to save and browse in visual studio settings may i will see the reason. Thank you all!